# Small sign connecting two signs

Tags: spacing, size

I would like to connect two symbols in mathmode by a smaller symbol, like $x_v y$, but the $v$ should be right in the middle. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "right in the middle". E.g., does middle refer to height of math symbols such as `+` and `-`?

Comment: Maybe you wish `$x \vee y$`, or not?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me exactly what you want, but it sounds like you want a letter `v` to be either an operation (like `+` or `\times`) or a relation (like `<` or `\le`). The spacing is slightly different:

[image]

On the other hand, maybe you want the `v` to be raised up a bit:

[image]

For convenience you can make this into a macro. Here is the code for the subscript version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\vop}{\mathop{{}_v}}
\newcommand{\vrel}{\mathrel{{}_v}}

\begin{document}

$x\vop y$

$x\vrel y$

\end{document}
```

For the raised version you can use

```
\newcommand{\vop}{\mathop{\raisebox{.1ex}{$\scriptstyle v$}}}
\newcommand{\vrel}{\mathrel{\raisebox{.1ex}{$\scriptstyle v$}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

$v$ should not be a subscript of $x$, but a subscript of "nothing" (that is, ${}$). Then you can specify spaces as desired, for example a thick space `\;`:

```tex
$x\;{}_v\;y$
```

[image]